# Large form seemingly remembering $_POST

Tags: php

I have a large form written in HTML (with 1,000+ `input` elements). I have set the action of the form to `update.php`, but was encountering some strange behaviour. It seems as though the $_POST is being reset somewhere along the lines.

Here's what `update.php` looks like:

```
<?php
empty($_POST);
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 3 October 2012
    [date2] => 
    [to] => 
    [number] => 0005
    [contact] => 
    [address] => 
    [contact_tel] => 
    [contact_fax] => 
    [contact_mob] => 
    [contact_email] => 
    [site_contact] => 
    [site_address] => 
    [site_contact_tel] => 
    [site_contact_fax] => 
    ...
);
```

The strange thing is that `$_POST['date']` has no value (i.e. it's an empty field). Even refreshing `update.php` and re-posting the form has no effect. The values that the PHP is reporting are the original values from the first time that I submitted the form.

Changing the action to `$_GET` functions as expected (i.e. the correct variables are passed in the link), but I cannot use this solution, mainly because the URL become too long and causes a server error.

Does anyone why this is occurring. I would post my code, but it's too long.

**Here's a PastBin of the form's HTML > http://pastebin.com/rdQujigK**

Comment: What is `empty($_POST);` for? And can you show us the form?

Comment: `empty($_POST)` is for my own debugging, to see if it had any effect on the $_POST values reported by `update.php`. It didn't. The form is too large to post here, so I've added to PasteBin > http://pastebin.com/rdQujigK

Comment: What do you think empty() does? It does not clear the array! It detects whether the parameter is "empty" and returns true or false. You do not use the return value, so nothing happens in this line besides wasting CPU.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was having a bit of a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ ... snip ... ]
<!-- Defaults: -->
<input type="text" value="3 October 2012" name="date" id="date" class="default_input" />
[ ... snip ... ]
```

I rest my case.

Comment: But it's not related to `date` only. For example `operative_name_1` also is not transferred. In fact, no edited values are passed through, and why does `empty($_POST)` have no effect?

Comment: 1. There are a bunch more defaults which overwrite entered values. 2. Because that line does nothing, not sure what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thank you, my fault. It seems a PHP error in the default section is not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

It's being submitted in the Defaults section:

`<input type="text" value="3 October 2012" name="date" id="date" class="default_input" />`